# Get the new image dimensions after rotate

Tags: php, rotation, gd

I'm rotating an image with gd library. `$_POST['rotation']` gives the rotation degrees. `$imagen` is an image instance with `getWidth()`, `setWidth()`, `getHeight()`, `setHeight()` and `setError()` methods:

```
//Get the new width and height
$x = floor( abs($imagen->getWidth() * cos(deg2rad($_POST['rotation']))) ) + floor( abs($imagen->getHeight() * sin(deg2rad($_POST['rotation']))) );
$y = floor( abs($imagen->getWidth() * sin(deg2rad($_POST['rotation']))) ) + floor( abs($imagen->getHeight() * cos(deg2rad($_POST['rotation']))) );

//Set the new width and height          
$imagen->setHeight($y);
$imagen->setWidth($x);

//Rotate image
if(!$canvas = imagerotate ($canvas, $_POST['rotation'], 0)) $imagen->setError('Error rotating');
```

The problem is that sometimes the `$x` and `$y` variables doesn't have the right values.
E.g. If I rotate 100º, I get `$x = 2364`, but the canvas width is 2362.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Update:**

I've tried to replace `abs` with `floor` and vice versa, and get weird result:

```
echo 'abs(floor) = '. (abs( floor($imagen->getAncho() * cos(deg2rad($_POST['rotacion']))) ) + abs( floor($imagen->getAlto() * sin(deg2rad($_POST['rotacion']))) ));
echo 'floor(abs) = '.(floor(abs($imagen->getAncho() * cos(deg2rad($_POST['rotacion']))) )+ floor(abs($imagen->getAlto() * sin(deg2rad($_POST['rotacion'])))));
```

Result:

```
abs(floor) = 2365 floor(abs) = 2364
```

I don't really understand why `abs()` changes the value.
Anyway, the real value is 2 pixels less than the `floor(abs)` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have failed to understand the below behavior, but I've found out an easier solution: get the canvas size, instead of calculating it:

```
if(!$canvas = imagerotate ($canvas, $_POST['rotation'], 0)) $imagen->setError('Error rotating');
//Set the new width and height          
$imagen -> setHeight( imagesy( $canvas ) );
$imagen -> setWidth( imagesx( $canvas ) );
```

and that's all!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `floor`. Instead, you should use `ceil`, which rounds the numbers upwards. Since you are rounding 2 numbers downwrds (floor), you can miss 2 pixels.

i.e. 2.5 pixels need 3 pixels on display, not just 2

Comment: The problem is the opposite. In the example, I get 2364 width, but the image is 2362 width.

Comment: I'm not sure what calculation is used by imagerotate itself, but the only thing i can imagine right now is that imagerotate rounds (floors) its values before making them absolute, so you could try swap floor and abs and test if it's better...

Comment: I've updated my question. I've tried what you say without success.